# After a heading, set dots up to the edge of the page

Tags: html, css

i'm currently trying to insert dots after a heading (h1/h2/h3) up to the margin. The problem is that the headings vary and I don't know exactly how to set points. so as an example fill H1 + 95% with points.

until now I could only create an automatic numbering, but no dots after a heading

```css
h2:before {
  content: counter(H2) " ";
  counter-increment: H2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: H3;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(H2) "." counter(H3) " ";
  counter-increment: H3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: H4;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<h2> ABC </h2>
<h2> ABCD </h2>
<h3> ANNCD </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieve by using the `::after` pseudo-element. You will want to use CSS flexbox on your `<h2>` and `<h3>` elements, so that you can force the `::after` pseudo-element to stretcht to the remaining width using `flex-grow: 1`.

Since CSS doesn't have the functionality to repeat a glyph over and over again, a really dumb workaround is simply to attempt to mimic the period using linear-gradient:

```css
h2::before {
  content: counter(H2) " ";
  counter-increment: H2;
  
  /* Arbitrary margin to mimic whitespace */
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: H3;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

h3::before {
  content: counter(H2) "." counter(H3) " ";
  counter-increment: H3;
  
  /* Arbitrary margin to mimic whitespace */
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: H4;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

/* Use display flex */
h2, h3 {
  display: flex;
}

/* Use ::after to fill up remaining space */
h2::after, h3::after {
    content: '';
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black .125em, white .125em);
    background-size: .25em .125em;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: .25em;
    margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<h2>ABC</h2>
<h2>ABCD</h2>
<h3>ANNCD</h3>
```

Another alternative will actually be using an SVG element that simply contains a `.` glyph in itself, i.e.:

```
<svg fill="black" width="5" height="10" viewBox="0 0 5 10"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="0" dy="10">.</text></svg>
```

Then, you simply [use this SVG as part of the data URI of the background image](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/), and use the same layout strategy as above:

```css
h2::before {
  content: counter(H2) " ";
  counter-increment: H2;
  
  /* Arbitrary margin to mimic whitespace */
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: H3;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

h3::before {
  content: counter(H2) "." counter(H3) " ";
  counter-increment: H3;
  
  /* Arbitrary margin to mimic whitespace */
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: H4;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

/* Use display flex */
h2, h3 {
  display: flex;
}

/* Use ::after to fill up remaining space */
h2::after, h3::after {
    content: '';
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="black" width="5" height="10" viewBox="0 0 5 10"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="0" dy="10">.</text></svg>');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: .25em;
    margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<h2>ABC</h2>
<h2>ABCD</h2>
<h3>ANNCD</h3>
```